# Get Next element based on a value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string as

```json
[
{"DataUnixTimestamp": 12345671, "DataColumn1": "Data Value 1", "DataColumn2": "Data Value 2"},
{"DataUnixTimestamp": 12345672, "DataColumn1": "Data Value 3", "DataColumn2": "Data Value 4"},
{"DataUnixTimestamp": 12345673, "DataColumn1": "Data Value 5", "DataColumn2": "Data Value 6"},
]
```

I have a value: 12345672. How do I find the next element's value that is 12345673?

This is what I have so far:

```
function findNextUnixTimestamp(inputTimestamp){
    var idx = jsonString.findIndex(x => +x.DataUnixTimestamp == inputTimestamp);
    if(idx >= 0){
          var nextDataUnixTimestamp = jsonString[idx +1].DataUnixTimestamp;
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working. How do I get the next element's timestamp?

Comment: Is `jsonString` an array or a string? `nextDataUnixTimestamp` is not used. Have you tried returning this value? You’re not checking if the next item exists in the first place.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?  Did you notice that your function doesn't return anything?

Comment: I have a data grid whose datasource is the json string. Based on a value, I'm trying to focus the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const json = `[ {"DataUnixTimestamp": 12345671, "DataColumn1": "Data Value 1", "DataColumn2": "Data Value 2"}, {"DataUnixTimestamp": 12345672, "DataColumn1": "Data Value 3", "DataColumn2": "Data Value 4"}, {"DataUnixTimestamp": 12345673, "DataColumn1": "Data Value 5", "DataColumn2": "Data Value 6"}]`;

function findNextUnixTimestamp(inputTimestamp) {
  const data = JSON.parse(json);
  const idx = data.findIndex(x => +x.DataUnixTimestamp == inputTimestamp);
  if (idx >= 0 && idx < data.length - 1) {
    return data[idx + 1].DataUnixTimestamp;
  }
}

console.log(findNextUnixTimestamp("12345672"));
console.log(findNextUnixTimestamp("12345673"));
```

or parse your JSON before function declaration

```
const json = `[ {"DataUnixTimestamp": 12345671, "DataColumn1": "Data Value 1", "DataColumn2": "Data Value 2"}, {"DataUnixTimestamp": 12345672, "DataColumn1": "Data Value 3", "DataColumn2": "Data Value 4"}, {"DataUnixTimestamp": 12345673, "DataColumn1": "Data Value 5", "DataColumn2": "Data Value 6"}]`;

const data = JSON.parse(json);

function findNextUnixTimestamp(inputTimestamp) {
  const idx = data.findIndex(x => +x.DataUnixTimestamp == inputTimestamp);
  if (idx >= 0 && idx < data.length - 1) {
    return data[idx + 1].DataUnixTimestamp;
  }
}
```

Comment: And if the function is called with 12345673?

Comment: @HereticMonkey then it returns `undefined`

Comment: The original code threw an error, since `data[idx + 1]` is undefined, and doesn't have a `DataUnixTimestamp` property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes that's truth, I fixed it after I realized that it didn't return `undefined` :>

Answer (score 0):

```
let yourTimeStamp = 12345671;

let getIndex = data.findIndex(x => x.DataUnixTimestamp === yourTimeStamp);

if(getIndex>-1 && (getIndex+1) in data){
    console.log(data[getIndex+1]["DataUnixTimestamp"])
}
else{
    console.log("array index out of bound")
}
```